# Increment date/time value by second with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to increment time in the given range of MySQL cells from the specific value + 1 second each time using the following query:

```
set @mytime= -1;
update wp_posts set post_date = date('2015-04-03 03:00:07') + interval (@mytime := @mytime + 1) second WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` > 229 AND `wp_posts`.`ID` < 999;
```

The problem is it sets correct time for the cell 229, but starting from cell 230 it begins from 00:00:00 and then adds 1 new second for every next cell, as expected.

So instead of

```
2015-04-03 03:00:06
2015-04-03 03:00:07
2015-04-03 03:00:08
etc
```

I have

```
2015-04-03 03:00:06
2015-04-03 00:00:00
2015-04-03 00:00:01
2015-04-03 00:00:02
and so on.
```

Where is the bug in the query?

Comment: `date()` extracts ONLY the date value from your string, so you're effectively doing `'2015-04-03' + interval ...`, so yeah, you strip off the time, thens tart adding on individual seconds again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('2015-04-03 03:00:07')` just returns the date part, it discards the time of day, so it's treated as being midnight when you add seconds to it. Change it to:

```
update wp_posts set post_date = cast('2015-04-03 03:00:07' AS DATETIME) + interval (@mytime := @mytime + 1) second WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` > 229 AND `wp_posts`.`ID` < 999;
```

The reason cell 229 wasn't affected by this is because your `WHERE` clause says `ID > 229`, not `ID >= 229`. So cell 229 isn't being updated at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've almost saved me. It works like a charm.

Comment: The funniest thing about that is that I've found your answer while googling further to catch my error. )